# Ruby: Sum selected hash values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-on-rails-4, inject

I've got an array of hashes and would like to sum up selected values. I know how to sum all of them or one of them but not how to select more than one key.

i.e.:

```
[{"a"=>5, "b"=>10, "active"=>"yes"}, {"a"=>5, "b"=>10, "active"=>"no"}, {"a"=>5, "b"=>10, "action"=>"yes"}]
```

To sum all of them I using:

```
t = h.inject{|memo, el| memo.merge( el ){|k, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v}}
=> {"a"=>15, "b"=>30, "active"=>"yesnoyes"} # I do not want 'active'
```

To sum one key, I do:

```
h.map{|x| x['a']}.reduce(:+)
=> 15
```

How do I go about summing up values for keys 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: Why not just do `h.map{|x| x['a'] + x['b'] }.reduce(:+)`?

Comment: Thanks @kardeiz for your comment. But it is returning 45. I should have made it clearer... What I'd like is:

    {'a'=>15, 'b'=>30}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `values_at`:

```
hs = [{:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => ""}, {:a => 2, :b => 4, :c => ""}]
keys = [:a, :b]
hs.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }.inject { |a, v| a.zip(v).map { |xy| xy.compact.sum }}
# => [3, 6]
```

If all required keys have values it will be shorter:

```
hs.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }.inject { |a, v| a.zip(v).map(&:sum) }
# => [3, 6]
```

If you want `Hash` back:

```
Hash[keys.zip(hs.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }.inject{ |a, v| a.zip(v).map(&:sum) })]
# => {:a => 3, :b => 6}
```

Comment: Thanks @VictorMoroz, your Hash example worked like a charm. 

Would you be able to explain what you are doing there? 

Thanks again,

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this:

```
a.map { |h| h.values_at("a", "b") }.transpose.map { |v| v.inject(:+) }
#=> [15, 30]
```

Step by step:

```
a.map { |h| h.values_at("a", "b") }   #=> [[5, 10], [5, 10], [5, 10]]
 .transpose                           #=> [[5, 5, 5], [10, 10, 10]]
 .map { |v| v.inject(:+) }            #=> [15, 30]
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan for your comment.

How can I add the key to the returned array. I'm expecting it to return:

    {'a'=>15, 'b'=>30}

Comment: `Hash[keys.zip(values)]`, e.g. `Hash[["a", "b"].zip([15, 30])]`

Answer (score 2):

How is this ?

```
h = [{"a"=>5, "b"=>10, "active"=>"yes"}, {"a"=>5, "b"=>10, "active"=>"no"}, {"a"=>5, "b"=>10, "action"=>"yes"}]
p h.map{|e| e.reject{|k,v| %w(active action).include? k } }.inject{|memo, el| memo.merge( el ){|k, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v}}
# >> {"a"=>15, "b"=>30}
```